# How to disable keys in windows (globally) using Qt?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, desktop

Is it possible to disable or block a key such as the <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> key?

my event filter:

```
bool EventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *object, QEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "object:" << object << "type:" << event->type();
    return false;
}
```

I tried use in `qApp`:

```
ui->setupUi(this);

EventFilter *evt = new EventFilter;

qApp->installEventFilter(evt);
```

But return only events from application widgets:

```
object: QWidgetWindow(0x175bae50, name = "QWidgetClassWindow") type: QEvent::Type(PlatformSurface)
object: QWidget(0x175b02c0) type: QEvent::Type(PlatformSurface)
object: QWidget(0x175b02c0) type: QEvent::Type(WinIdChange)
object: QWidget(0x175b02c0) type: QEvent::Type(Create)
...
```

And:

```
ui->setupUi(this);

EventFilter *evt = new EventFilter;

QDesktopWidget *c = new QDesktopWidget;
c->installEventFilter(evt);
```

But return only 2 events:

```
object: QDesktopWidget(0x174e0260, name = "desktop") type: QEvent::Type(PolishRequest)
object: QDesktopWidget(0x174e0260, name = "desktop") type: QEvent::Type(Polish)
```

Can not intercept and / or block events? Thanks

Comment: If you want to disable keys globally then qt will be hardly of any help. You'll need to dig into keyboard hooks and related low-level stuff.

Comment: Also, latest Windows is pretty restrictive about what applications can do. You'd probably have to request admin privileges from the user, if you wanted to mess with something like print screen key. Not sure, it *could* also be that an application can disable it, but my guess is, no.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: I think you can do it but it need to restart OS. i will put it as answer if it's  good enough for you?

Comment: @Alf To make it difficult to get print out of the application screen, I know I can not completely stop it, but I would like to make it difficult.

I can intercept the "print" key when the application window is in focus, but if I click on the "taskbar" and hit the "print" event does not occur, so I wanted to block globally while the application is open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install a [low-level keyboard hook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644985(v=vs.85).aspx) to intercept and block all <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> presses. The following is tested on my windows 7 machine.

Here is a minimal example that shows how to do this:

[image: ScreenShot]

```
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <windows.h>
//link against user32.lib when compiling in MSVC
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")
#endif

class GlobalPrintScreenBlocker {
public:
    GlobalPrintScreenBlocker():mHKeyboardHook(NULL) {}
    //to avoid leaking the hook procedure handle
    ~GlobalPrintScreenBlocker(){ unblock(); }
    //hook callback function (called on every system-wide key press)
    static LRESULT CALLBACK LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode,
                                                 WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        if(nCode == HC_ACTION) {
            PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT p = reinterpret_cast<PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT>(lParam);
            if(p->vkCode == VK_SNAPSHOT) return 1; //block print-screen key
        }
        //this is not a message we are interested in
        return CallNextHookEx(NULL, //ignored paramater
                              nCode,
                              wParam,
                              lParam);
    }
    void block(){
        mHKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, //low-level keyboard hool
                                          &LowLevelKeyboardProc, //callback
                                          GetModuleHandle(NULL), 
                                          0);
    }
    void unblock(){
        if(mHKeyboardHook) UnhookWindowsHookEx(mHKeyboardHook);
        mHKeyboardHook = NULL;
    }

private:
    HHOOK mHKeyboardHook;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    GlobalPrintScreenBlocker blocker;
    QPushButton button("Disable ScreenShot");
    button.setCheckable(true);
    QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::toggled, [&](bool isChecked){
        if(isChecked)
            blocker.block();
        else
            blocker.unblock();
    });
    button.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

The hook gets called in the thread that installed it. This has the advantages of not having to worry about thread-safety issues in your callback function, and that there would be no difference between 32-bit processes and 64-bit processes (all processes will end up calling the hook function indirectly by posting a message to the event loop of the thread that installed the hook). However, this also has the disadvantage that if your thread was busy (executing anything else) the callback hook might not get called:

> The hook procedure should process a message in less time than the data entry specified in the LowLevelHooksTimeout value ... The value is in milliseconds. If the hook procedure times out, the system passes the message to the next hook. However, on Windows 7 and later, the hook is silently removed without being called. There is no way for the application to know whether the hook is removed.

You can get around this limitation by allocating a separate thread for installing/executing the hook. Also, note that your hook's callback function should be as minimum as possible in order for it to be able to finish within the time constraints.

P.S.: I had to use the snipping tool to create the screen shot above. . .

Comment: Mike, your example work fine in MSVC and Mingw, THANKS!! I will send a bounty for you. :D (after 23 hours)

Comment: One more thing can workaround this defense. If someone sets another keyboard hook getting the screenshot, it may have called before your hook. Even more simple way is to use any screen capture tool without printscreen key usage. I think you can't prohibit screen capturing at all.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov , you're right with that. I don't think that there is a way to prohibit that completely. After all, there is nothing that can stop the user from directing  the screen output to any other device where they can capture a photo of it, and that would render any time you invest implementing a video driver that disables screen capturing at the system level utterly useless. Any approach you follow to implement such a feature should just aim to make it somehow hard for the user to capture the screen, installing a hook to disable the snapshot button is such an approach. . .

Comment: Although, I completely admit that one can use the *Snipping Tool* to bypass this approach completely (as mentioned in my answer). But I wanted to focus on the question scope, that is, *disable keys in windows globally*

Comment: No problem. The answer is good (+my upvote). Low-level global hooks are extremely useful for other purposes also. For example, it can help to record all user actions for generating GUI automation scripts though there are many more pitfalls except hooks.